# Display a full screen app over another apps

Tags: flutter, mobile-application, flutter-plugin

I want to display a flutter app screen over another apps on a user device by selecting the apps from list of installed apps. How can I do so ?

I've tried different plugins like flutter overlay over other apps, flutter window manager but I'm not able to get how can I overlay my flutter app screen over another apps as a complete screen view.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.